# How to use bp-members/bp-members-functions.php in child theme

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, user-registration

I am altering bp-members/bp-members-functions.php bp_core_signup_user where if user type is 'XXX', sending out a mail with activation link. If user type is 'YYY', sending out a mail without activation link. It is working fine after coding.

I just wanted to check is it possible we could create bp-members in child theme? The only worry I have is, if I take an update of buddypress, I shouldn't loose what's been coded in bp-members-functions.php. Also, I do not want to block the updates.

Is there any other better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way (future proof) way of doing it. You can use a filter:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

If you would like to change the email subject you can use:

```
bp_core_signup_send_validation_email_subject
```

To change the email body, use:

```
bp_core_signup_send_validation_email_message
```